# Trying to remove outliers in R for ggplot with excel file

Tags: r

[image: ExampleDataTable]

```
ggplot(data = Flint %>% filter(Flint$Lead <=7), aes(y=Flint$Lead, group=Flint$Ward)) + geom_boxplot() + stat_boxplot()
```

I have an excel file which Im trying to ggplot. I have to remove all values above 7 from the ggplot as its considered an outlier. I have tried to use subset and filter but am receiving this error. Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5): y, group Is there a way I can get the data for Flint$First_Draw to be all values below . Sample Output would be multiple box plots based on wards. An example would be Ward 1: Lead 5.0 6.3, Ward 2: Lead 3.6, Ward 3: 2.8. For Ward 1 Lead 7.8 wouldn't appear as it is an outlier and is above 7. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Do not post code or data as images because then we have to retype everything in order to test it.

Comment: I edited it to make it a reproducible example :). Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Without a `dput` of your `Flint` data set, as explained in the link above, we are unlikely to be able to do much to help.

Comment: Instead of `data = Flint` try `data = Flint[Flint$First_Draw < 50, ]`

Comment: @G5W it gave the same error unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `Flint$` elements from the `aes` call then it should work.

This works:

```
data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars %>% filter(mpg <= 20), aes(y = hp, group = cyl)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

But this fails with a similar error message:

```
ggplot(mtcars %>% filter(mtcars$mpg <= 20), aes(y = mtcars$hp, group = mtcars$cyl)) +
  geom_boxplot()

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (18): y, group
```

Comment: I tried changing it to use just the name of the column but it still gave me the same error. That works if the column isn't the same as y or group